# Procedure or function expects parameter '@id' which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql

what am I missing?

```
private void GetGeneralData(ReportPackage myPackage)
{
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(mySqlConn))
  {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[GetStuff]", conn))
    {
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", myPackage.IdDeliverable);

      conn.Open();
      using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
        dr.Read();
        myPackage.DeployServer = dr.GetString(0);
        myPackage.Connection = dr.GetString(1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> Procedure or function 'GetStuff' expects parameter '@id', which was not supplied.

Comment: What is the definition of `myPackage.IdDeliverable`? What data type is it? Could it be null?

Comment: @krillgar It's not, it comes filled with a string of 13 characters. At least when I debug it =)

Comment: Why is people down-scoring the question without as negative without explaining why? At least be more declarative so that way I don't do it again.

Comment: I'd imagine that you have nothing in your question other than "What am I missing?" and a block of code. At least you have an error message, but you're not giving any further details of what is going on, or what you think is going on. In order for people to help you, and your question to help people in the future, more details (especially showing that you have at least some understanding of what is going on) are always appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding

`cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`

Comment: Wow, that was it, the engine can not infer this? Do you know why?

Comment: My guess is because you could also put just inline sql in your sqlcommand and since its just a string either way it doesnt know its a stored procedure unless you tell it. Thats just my guess

Answer (score 2):

You're executing the stored procedure as a *statement*, not as a *stored procedure*. It is as if you opened a query window in SQL Server Management Studio and typed

```
[dbo].[GetStuff]
GO
```

So even though the stored procedure takes a parameter, since you're executing a textual statement, it can't map the parameter to anything in the text. Change the command type to `CommandType.StoredProcedure`.

You might find you code a little more compact, too, if you do a little refactoring, thus:

```
private void GetGeneralData( ReportPackage myPackage )
{
  using ( SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(mySqlConn) )
  using ( SqlCommand    cmd  = conn.CreateCommand() )
  {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure ;
      cmd.CommandText = "dbo.GetStuff" ;

      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", myPackage.IdDeliverable);

      conn.Open();
      using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
        dr.Read();
        myPackage.DeployServer = dr.GetString(0);
        myPackage.Connection   = dr.GetString(1);
      }
  }
   return ;
}
```

Comment: I went for `using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                CommandText = "[dbo].[GetStuff]", Connection = conn
            })`

But that is an excelent explanation! thanks.

Comment: @apacay: it provides a hook for placing debugger breakpoints. Further, I prefer to make things explicit rather than relying on quiet default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[spSearch_Stock]
(
    @KeyW varchar(50),
    @Empty int

)
AS
BEGIN
SET @Empty = (SELECT COUNT(Customer) FROM tbl_Stock)

IF @Empty > 0 
    SELECT StockID,Abb ,LotNo ,InvoiceNo ,TeaState,Customer ,Broker ,TeaGrade,Pkgs,NetWeight ,TotWeight ,PriceUSD,CurrencyRate,TotalAmtUSD,BrokerageUSD
    FROM tbl_Stock

    WHERE 
    (Abb) LIKE '%'+@Keyw+'%' 


    ORDER BY 
    StockID ASC,Abb ASC

        ELSE 
        SELECT 'null' as StockID,'null' as Abb ,'null' as LotNo ,'null' as InvoiceNo ,'null' as TeaState,'null' as Customer ,'null' as Broker ,'null' as TeaGrade,'null' as Pkgs,'null' as NetWeight ,'null' as TotWeight ,'null' as PriceUSD,'null' as CurrencyRate,'null' as TotalAmtUSD,'null' as  BrokerageUSD

END
```